# Rails 3 - How to escape from subdomain route to the normal route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I've worked on making a multiple subdomains feature for my E-commerce website. So far, I've made it possible to assign a ':subdomain' attribute for every user and display their sites on like 'subdomain.example.com'.

But, I cannot return to 'example.com' from 'subdomain.example.com' because the 'root_path' leads to not 'example.com' but 'subdomain.example.com'.

routes.rb file:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  match "/" => 'contributors#show'
end

root :to => "items#index"
```

The Subdomain class comes from 'domains.rb' file below.

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www"
  end
end
```

contributors#show

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path # this leads to contributor#show. wanna make it to index#show. %>
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `root_url(:subdomain => false)`? This strips the link of the subdomain and should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rails takes the first matching path defined in the routes.rb file. If you are on the subdomain the constraint matches and match "/" matches as root path.
Try move "root :to => 'items#index'" to the top of your routes.rb file.

Comment: I've tried it out, it made it possible to go to 'items#index', but also made it impossible to access to subdomain.example.com.

Comment: maybe you can create another constraint (e.g. CommonDomain) around the "root" route declaration.